# ValueError: Shapes (69, 44, 2) and (69, 2, 2) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using TensorFlow version 1.3.0 in Python 3.5.2. I'm trying to build a Convolution Neural Network that takes in data with 69 rows and 44 independent values to perform a binary classification (that is, either a jump or a fall), but keep getting the error:

```
    ValueError: Shapes (69, 44, 2) and (69, 2, 2) are incompatible
```

I'm not exactly sure where the code changes the size from 44 columns down to 2. The code for the Network I've constructed is mostly from the tensorflow tutorial for the MNIST database that has been modified to address my data/problem. The main differences being, that I'm using conv1d() instead of conv2d(), and I'm not using any pooling layers. The code is as follows:

```
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  """Model function for CNN."""
  # Input Layer
  #-1 will be filled by a 69 later on
  #44 used for independent vars, 1 must be used for input in tf.layers.conv1d()
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 44, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv1d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=1,
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu,
      name = "Alan")

  # Convolutional Layer #2
  conv2 = tf.layers.conv1d(
      inputs=conv1,
      filters=64,
      kernel_size=1,
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu,
      name = "Borris")

  # Dense Layer
  dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=conv2, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  # Logits Layer
  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=2)
  print(logits)

  predictions = {
      # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
      "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
      # `logging_hook`.
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
  }

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

  # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
  onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=2)
  loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
      onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

  # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
          labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

Here is where the problem occurs, as soon as I run eval_input_fn:

```
jumpupdown_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/jumpupdown_convnet_model")

tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

# Train the model
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": mTrainDat},
      y=mTrainLab,
      batch_size=69,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)

jumpupdown_classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=20000,
      hooks=[logging_hook])

# Evaluate the model and print results
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": mTestDat},
      y=mTestLab,
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
eval_results = jumpupdown_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print(eval_results)
```

To clarify a bit more, mTrainDat looks like the following:

```
array([[ 0.23971076,  0.24687247, -0.22665831, ...,  0.73542702,
        -0.57439029, -0.22714323],
       [ 0.32290912,  0.61977148, -0.4258523 , ...,  0.73542702,
         0.74438596, -0.57915074],
       [ 0.41255337,  0.2795991 , -0.56257713, ..., -0.30046052,
         0.74438596,  0.74211949],
       ..., 
       [ 0.56027043,  1.63016009,  1.36453617, ...,  0.57338732,
         0.74438596,  0.56973094],
       [-0.1470048 ,  1.23301661,  0.63612264, ...,  0.73542702,
         0.58223492,  0.74211949],
       [-0.46544313,  1.02278185,  0.30256116, ..., -1.38631892,
         0.74438596,  0.57966185]], dtype=float32)
```

Where mTrainLab looks like this:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.],
    ........
   [ 0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

And where the mTestDat and mTestLab look similar, but contain only 6 rows.

I've tried changing values around in an attempt to diagnose the problem, but have been unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated.